# Column Validation Forumla Question Regarding Special Characters and ASCII

Tags: 2010, development, validation, special-characters

I've run in a problem writing a formula that will basically validate what the user enters. So for example, i need a user to input a password using the following criteria:

- 12 characters long
- 1st character must be an Uppercase Letter
- Characters 2-10 must be Lowercase letters
- Character 11 must be one of the following special characters (!@$*+)
- Character 12 must be a number 0-9

Below I have everything but the special characters figured out, in my example code I am currently using only one special character at the moment (!). Below is what i have so far and i cant figure out how to get those specified special characters to validate on character 11. ASCII number code separates them (! = 33, @ = 64, $ = 36, * = 42, + = 43), would be perfect if i could just have those specified special characters validate on character 11, any suggestions?:

```
=(LEN(BOPassword)=12)
+(CODE(MID(BOPassword,1,1))>64)
+(CODE(MID(BOPassword,1,1))<91)
+(CODE(MID(BOPassword,2,1))>96)
+(CODE(MID(BOPassword,2,1))<123)
+(CODE(MID(BOPassword,3,1))>96)
+(CODE(MID(BOPassword,3,1))>123)
+(CODE(MID(BOPassword,4,1))>96)
+(CODE(MID(BOPassword,4,1))<123)
+(CODE(MID(BOPassword,5,1))>96)
+(CODE(MID(BOPassword,5,1))<123)
+(CODE(MID(BOPassword,6,1))>96)
+(CODE(MID(BOPassword,6,1))<123)
+(CODE(MID(BOPassword,7,1))>96)
+(CODE(MID(BOPassword,7,1))<123)
+(CODE(MID(BOPassword,8,1))>96)
+(CODE(MID(BOPassword,8,1))<123)
+(CODE(MID(BOPassword,9,1))>96)
+(CODE(MID(BOPassword,9,1))<123)
+(CODE(MID(BOPassword,10,1))>96)
+(CODE(MID(BOPassword,10,1))<123)
+(CODE(MID(BOPassword,11,1))>32)
+(CODE(MID(BOPassword,11,1))<34)
+(CODE(MID(BOPassword,12,1))>47)
+(CODE(MID(BOPassword,12,1))<58)
=25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IF` as below

```
IF(CODE(MID(BOPassword,11,1))<>33,IF(CODE(MID(BOPassword,11,1))<>64,IF(CODE(MID(BOPassword,11,1))<>36,IF(CODE(MID(BOPassword,11,1))<>42,IF(CODE(MID(BOPassword,11,1))<>43,0,1),1),1),1),1)
```

The above will return 1 if position 11 contains any of code `33 or 64 or 36 or 42 or 43` else it return 0

Comment: Thank for your prompt response. If I add this to my code do I need to input (after my last code for character 12) an AND= then put in your following if statements? SharePoint's formula and how it accepts syntax confused even after reading many guides.  @Amal Hashim

Comment: Yes you can and `AND` and use the `IF` to check for position 11 OR you just replace the `+(CODE(MID(BOPassword,11,1))>32)` with the `IF` statement and give it a try.

Comment: I still can get SharePoint 2010 to accept the IF statement, I've used an =OR and a =AND to load in the IF Statement but it dislikes it each time :(

Comment: Please ignore my last statement. I was having a spacing issue in the syntax! So SP accepted my formula with my added =AND and your IF statements. Do you know if the last line (=24) would be =30? Is each If statement another +1 along with the =AND being +1?

Comment: The complete if will return 1. so you can check = 24

Comment: I appreciate you helping me through this process. I have tried everything and it still wont validate, I used numerous =24 =25 =26, I've used the AND and put in the IF statement in various places and it keeps throwing an error when I type in the password correctly. Any suggestions?

Comment: Remove everything and add one piece at a time. I would first make sure the if is working.. then add remaining one by one validating each usecase.

Comment: It doesn't like the IF statement, I put it in as +IF(CODE(MID(BOPassword,11,1))<>33,1) and it accepts it but when I go to test it it comes back with a validation error. I've also tried +(IF(CODE(MID(BOPassword,11,1))<>33,1)) and +AND(IF(CODE(MID(BOPassword,11,1))<>33,1)) with no success